# How to implement EXCEL's lookup function in Python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have been trying to figure out how to implement a feature similar to EXCEL's `VLOOKUP` function in Python in order to combine multiple datasets using a common value. I figured out a way that indeed works, but I feel like it is not the best solution. In the example below, I limited my datasets to only three in order to illustrate my problem, but in reality, I may have numerous datasets

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

time_a   = np.arange(0, 10010, 10)
data_a1  = np.random.randint(1500, 2500, 1001)
data_a2  = np.random.randint(750, 1500, 1001)

time_b   = np.arange(0, 10005, 5)
data_b1  = np.random.randint(0, 10, 2001)
data_b2  = np.random.randint(0, 20, 2001)
data_b3  = np.random.randint(0, 15, 2001)

time_c   = np.arange(0, 10030, 30)

df_a     = pd.DataFrame({'time_a': time_a, 'data_a1': data_a1, 'data_a2': data_a2})
df_b     = pd.DataFrame({'time_b': time_b, 'data_b1': data_b1, 'data_b2': data_b2, 'data_b3': data_b3})
df_c     = pd.DataFrame({'time_c': time_c})

df_a_c   = pd.merge_asof(df_c, df_a, left_on=['time_c'], right_on=['time_a'])
df_a_b_c = pd.merge_asof(df_a_c, df_b, left_on=['time_c'], right_on=['time_b'])
```

In order for this to work, I need to use `pd.merge_asof` twice considering the fact that I got three datasets (which I would like to avoid). Since I now end up with three different times that are the same (`time_a`, `time_b`, and `time_c`), it would also, perhaps, be convenient to rename one of them into `time` and remove the other two:

```
df_a_b_c.rename(columns={'time_c':'time'}, inplace=True)
df_a_b_c.drop(columns=['time_a', 'time_b'])
```

Inspired by https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/124964/vlookup-in-python, I also tried to use without any luck

```
def vlookup(key, table, column, approximate_match=True):
    compare = key.__ge__ if approximate_match else key.__eq__
    try:
        return max(row for row in table if compare(row[0]))[column]
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

- It is possible to do this using, for example, numpy or do I have to make a detour through pandas?
- Do I have to use `pd.merge_asof` multiple times to combine multiple datasets?
- What if I only want to select certain columns and not combine the entire datasets, is that possible?
- What is the recommended practice in Python?

I highly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.searchsorted` does the same as VLOOKUP (actually, the same as INDEX + MATCH) with a -1 or +1 (sorted up or down) set.

```
df_a     = pd.DataFrame({'time': time_a, 'data_a1': data_a1, 'data_a2': data_a2})
df_b     = pd.DataFrame({'time': time_b, 'data_b1': data_b1, 'data_b2': data_b2, 'data_b3': data_b3})
df_c     = pd.DataFrame({'time': time_c})

for df in [df_a, df_b]:
    for c in df.columns:
        if c == 'time':
            continue
        df_c[c] = df[c].iloc[np.clip(df['time'].searchsorted(df_c.time), 0, len(df)-1)].values
```